# Help with reading a blurry circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis

I read the paper "[Digital sound processing using Arduino and MATLAB](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7237295)" and there is a circuit there, you can see it in this photo:

[image]

Can anyone please help me read it properly?

Is the 2 resistors connect to DAC or only the upper one?

What is the capacitor size in the audio in? (is it 10uf? 10 pf?)

Answer (score 3):

Both resistors on the left are connected for DC bias and the capacitor is for coupling. The value of the cap is 10 µF (e.g coupling a 100 Hz signal).

Comment: oh, my bad. Then .. I think both of them are connected, seems like an hardware mixing circuit and I suppose that pin 11 and pin 3 are configured as PWM outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The resistors are connected together on the right to add the two PWM outputs. One is 1M and the other 3.9K (ratio about 256:1).

The capacitor should be about 2nF to attenuate the high frequency harmonics but looks like it might be 1nF or 100pF. That will allow a lot of high frequency noise into the amplifier, which could cause issues such as excessive heating of the speaker. The author appears to assume if you can’t hear the noise it isn’t important.

The input cap is 10uF, note the polarity (+ side to Arduino input).

Comment: Do you think the circuit should be improved by replacing the output capacitor from 1 nF / 100pF (not yet known for sure) to 2 nF?
Or will it not be better?

Comment: I think it will be better with 2nF.